# Skeleton directory - how to add my own directories

Tags: linux, useradd, defaults, mkdir

I want to add a few directories to the skeleton directory. When I add new user I want to add my own directories to the new home directories.

Comment: `mkdir /etc/skel/blahblah`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As [thrig pointed out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/285708/skeleton-directory-how-to-add-my-own-directories#comment497800_285708), all that's needed is to create the directory structure that you want under `/etc/skel`.

Quoting from the [useradd man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/useradd)

> -k, --skel SKEL_DIR
>
> The skeleton directory, which contains files and directories to be copied in the user's home directory, when the home directory is created by useradd.
>   This option is only valid if the -m (or --create-home) option is specified.
>
> If this option is not set, the skeleton directory is defined by the SKEL variable in /etc/default/useradd or, by default, /etc/skel.

... and the default SKEL variable in /etc/default/useradd is /etc/skel.

Answer (score 0):

According to useradd -D

```
 GROUP=100
 HOME=/home
 INACTIVE=-1
 EXPIRE=
 SHELL=/bin/bash
 SKEL=/etc/skel
 GROUPS=video,dialout
 CREATE_MAIL_SPOOL=no
```

SKEL= [path] is your skeleton directory.